# How do I get obfuscated text using the font parameter in raw JSON text?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to `/tellraw` scrambled letters.

```
/tellraw @a {"text":"welcome to this domain server","FONT":"something}
```

`minecraft:uniform` works to make uniform font. I want scrambled letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to make illegible text:

- ```
  {"text":"You aren't going to read this in a million years.","obfuscated":true}
  ```

  This is the most common way of creating scrambled text. This will scramble the letters normally.
- ```
  {"text":"Wait, are you actually trying to translate this?","font":"minecraft:alt"}
  ```

  The `minecraft:alt` font is the font used as decoration in enchantment tables. This doesn't make the text constantly scramble. You could use this as a translation challenge in a map.

Those are the two ways of making illegible text. You could combine them, like so:

```
{"text":"You aren't going to read this in a BAZILLION years.","obfuscated":true,"font":"minecraft:alt"}
```

and that would make sure that no one finds out what the text says, ever.
<sup>(unless they look at the commands)</sup>